# Can a Sum of distinct squares ever equal power of two?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Does there exist $2^t,\ t\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ which can be express as Sum of two or more distinct square number.

> Or
>
> Can it be shown that
>
> $$\begin{split}2^t &\ne \sum a_i^2 = a_1^2+ a_2^2+\cdots+a_n^2\end{split}$$
>
> Where $n\ge 2$ and $\{a_i,t\}\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ and $a_i \ne a_j$ for $1\le i,j \le n$

Example: $2^6=64=7^2+3^2+2^2+1^2+1^2$ here $1^2$ repeat two times so this is not allowed.

My incomplete attempt for arithmetic squares

> Edit: check related new post, [Can a sum arithmetic square ever equal to power of two?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3564360/647719)

Let $n,u,d\in\mathbb{Z}_+$

$$\begin{split}\sum_{q=0}^u (n+qd)^2 &=n^2+(n+d)^2+(n+2d)^2+\cdots+(n+ud)^2\\ &=n^2(u+1)+\frac{(u+1)u}{2}(2nd+d^2)+\frac{(u+1)u(u-1)}{3}d^2 \end{split}$$

Let
$$\begin{split}2^t &=\sum_{q=0}^u (n+qd)^2 \\ \implies 3\cdot 2^{t+1}&=6n^2(u+1)+3(u+1)u(2nd-d^2)+(u+1)u(u-1)2d^2 \\ &= (u+1)(6n^2+3u(2nd+d^2)+u(u-1)2d^2)\\ &(in\ case,\ u+1= 3) \\
\implies 2^t&= 3n^2+3(2nd+d^2)+2d^2\\ &= n^2+(n+1)^2+(n+2d)^2 \end{split}$$

Now we need to simplify for case, $6n^2+3u(2nd+d^2)+u(u-1)2d^2=3\cdot2^x$ and $u+1=2^y$ where $x+y=t+1$ but I'm stuck here. Thank you.

Related post:

[Can a sum of consecutive $n$th powers ever equal a power of two?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3369713/647719)

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018801/numbers-which-are-not-the-sum-of-distinct-squares)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexample: For $t=8, n = 5$ and $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5)=(1,5,7,9,10)$ we have:

$$2^8=1^2+5^2+7^2+9^2+10^2$$

Comment: Is there any example for $2^t=n^2+(n+d)^2+(n+2d)^2+\cdots +(n+ud)^2$?

Comment: @Pruthviraj, do you mean consecutive squares as in $n^2+(n+1)^2+...+(n+k)^2$ or are the numbers under the square in an arithmetic progression? I am unclear about your notation with $+d,+2d,...,+ud$.

Comment: @Pruthviraj, If you mean consecutive squares as $n^2+(n+1)^2+\ldots+(n+k)^2$, there is no solution. And we can prove it relatiely easy using the sum for consecutive squares $\sum_{i=1}^ni^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$.

Comment: Notation $d$ denotes positive integer example: let $d=3,n=2,u=2$ so $n^2+(n+d)^2+(n+2d)^2= 2^2+5^2+8^2=93$. I already some work on $\sum_{q=0}^{u}(n+qd)$ in given post. I am asking about inducing $d$.

Comment: @Pruthviraj, I understand, they are squares of an arithmetic progression ($d$ is the common difference), not consecutive squares.

Answer (score 2):

We have, for instance,
$$
169 + 49 + 25 + 9 + 4=256
$$

Answer (score 0):

No.  2 is a direct prime in the gaussian integers, which means that some power of it is twice another mumber.  Thus 1+i squared is 2i, whereas 2+i squared is 3+4i.

Since the sum of two squares equate to non-direct numbers squared, it does not happen for direct numbers.

A similar thing is seen in eisenstein numbers, which leads to a^2+ab+b^2 being square.  3 divides instances, but you get free powers only for numbers comprised of primes 6n+1.

Answer (score 0):

It would be extremely surprising if the answer were no. Consider just the first $n$ squares. There are $2^n$ ways to construct distinct sums of these, and each sum adds up to something between $0$ and $\frac16(2n^3-3n^2+n)$ which is approximately $\frac{n^3}3$.

But $2^n$ is *vastly* larger than $\frac{n^3}3$. Consider even a small number like $n=80$. On the one hand we have $2^{80}$ which is the number of atoms in the universe and on the other we have the everyday number 173,880.

What are the chances that any of the $\frac{n^3}3$ possible sums $S$ is so unusual that *none* of the $2^n$ possible selections of squares adds up to $S$? There would have to be a very good reason, and it would not be a subtle one.

Instead, we should guess that the opposite is true: except for a few very small exceptions, *every* power of 2 should be representable as a sum of distinct squares in a great many ways.

Comment: For example, 100 is a sum of distinct squares in only 2 ways ($100 = 1+9+16+25+49 = 36+64$) but 1000 is a sum of distinct squares in 1269 different ways ($1000 = 961+25+9+4+1 = 900+64+36 = \ldots = 225 + 196 + 144 + 121 + 100 + 81 + 64 + 49 + 16 + 4$) and 2000 is a sum of distinct squares in 27,526 different ways.