# In how many ways can a number be decomposed in a sum of distinct perfect squares

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, number-theory, real-numbers

Is there a formula for how many ways can a number be decomposed in sum of distinct perfect squares.

Example: $$50 = 49 + 1 = 1 + 4 + 9 + 36 = 9 + 16 + 25$$

The number 50 can be decomposed in 3 different ways.

Comment: If you are talking about **distinct** squares, then not every random number can be decomposed into squares. For example, $6$ cannot be decomposed into perfect squares.

Comment: Yes, I meant perfect squares. I also edited the info. @DevanshKamra

Comment: also 50 = 25+25

Comment: @Lozenges They have to be distinct, I will also edit that in the info

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Edit: Added a plot of $a_n$ and its asymptotics, corrected numerics. Also, a
**short answer**: There's not really a formula, but people can work out its growth.)

Denote $a_n = $ number of ways to write $n$ as a sum of distinct squares.

Here we demonstrate, though not quite a formula (as you might expect), how we can compute $a_n$ by using the *generating function* for $a_n $. Indeed, we have
$$
A =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n q^n = \prod_{k=1}^\infty(1+q^{k^2})=(1+q)(1+q^4)(1+q^9)(1+q^{16})\cdots \qquad(\dagger)
$$
(Why does this work? Pretend you are expanding this product and keep track of the powers of $q$ that you collected.)

You can play around to see what these values are (choose a large enough $N$) with SageMath (https://sagecell.sagemath.org/):

```
var('q')
N = 10
A = 1
for k in range(1,N):
    A = A*(1+q^(k^2))
A.expand()
```

This computes the first $N=10$ product in $(\dagger)$, and gives

```
 ...+ 4*q^65 + q^64 + q^63 + 3*q^62 + 2*q^61 + q^59 + q^58 + q^57 + q^56 + q^55 + 2*q^54 + 2*q^53 + q^52 + q^51 + 3*q^50 + 2*q^49 + 2*q^46 + 2*q^45 + q^42 + 2*q^41 + q^40 + q^39 + q^38 + q^37 + q^36 + q^35 + q^34 + 2*q^30 + 2*q^29 + 2*q^26 + 2*q^25 + q^21 + q^20 + q^17 + q^16 + q^14 + q^13 + q^10 + q^9 + q^5 + q^4 + q + 1
```

(truncated)

Note the coefficient in front of $q^{50}$ is $3$, so there are three such decompositions for 50. As another example, the coefficient of $q^{65}$ is 4, so we have four such decompositions for 65. The term $q^{60}$ is missing, this means there is no such decomposition for 60.

In any case, you can compute $a_n$ by using its generating function $A$ and look at the coefficients of $q^n$ in $A$. (And Use a suitably large $N>\sqrt n$, computationally, so you don't miss any decompositions. See **update edit** below for a SageMath implementation of this.)

Some observation is that it seems quite "sparse", these decompositions are rare as the power of $q$ in the factor $(1+q^{k^2})$ grows quite quickly. However this does not imply every integer $n$ has small $a_n$. Indeed, as $n$ increases so will $a_n$. For instance $a_{1000} = 1269,a_{10000} = 3296089777$, and $a_{100000} = 2759256389896728737285379 $. Here is a plot of $a_n$ (in $\color{purple} {\rm purple}$) for $n\le 1000$ using SageMath (code to plot this at the end):

[image]

Now, with these several terms of $a_n$, we can search on OEIS which gives this reference here: http://oeis.org/A033461 . There doesn't seem to have a nice closed formula for $a_n$, but people have estimated its asymptotic growth (Vaclav Kotesovec, Dec 09 2016):

$$
a_n \sim \exp(3 * 2^{-5/3}  \pi^{1/3}  ((\sqrt{2}-1)\zeta(3/2))^{2/3}  n^{1/3}) \frac{(\sqrt{2}-1)\zeta(3/2))^{1/3} }{ 2^{4/3} \sqrt{3} \pi^{1/3} n^{5/6}},
$$
where $\zeta(3/2)\approx 2.612375$ is the Zeta function at $3/2$ . This asymptotic is ploted in $\color{yellow} {\rm yellow}$ above. Such an asymptotic estimate is often found by doing some (complex) analysis on the generating function $A(q)$ mentioned above (a typical method is called *saddle-point method*. A great reference is
*Analytic Combinatorics* by Philippe Flajolet and Robert Sedgewick). I do not know the exact detail of this particular asymptotic, however.

An simple question to ask is: Is $a_n\neq 0 $ for all sufficiently large $n$? Or are there "gaps", that $a_n = 0$ infinitely often? One would guess it is the former by looking at the plot above, and indeed it is true:

**Theorem.** The number $128$ is the largest integer that cannot be written as a sum of distinct squares. And a complete list of positive integers $n$ that cannot be written as a sum of distinct squares are:
$$2,
 3,
 6,
 7,
 8,
 11,
 12,
 15,
 18,
 19,
 22,
 23,
 24,
 27,
 28,
 31,
 32,
 33,\\
 43,
 44,
 47,
 48,
 60,
 67,
 72,
 76,
 92,
 96,
 108,
 112,
 128.$$

Proofs and references of this can be found here: [https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Numbers_not_Sum_of_Distinct_Squares#:~:text=Then%20k%20can%20be%20expressed,distinct%20squares%20by%20Induction%20Hypothesis](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Numbers_not_Sum_of_Distinct_Squares#:%7E:text=Then%20k%20can%20be%20expressed,distinct%20squares%20by%20Induction%20Hypothesis) and here: [Numbers which are not the sum of distinct squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018801/numbers-which-are-not-the-sum-of-distinct-squares) .

**Postscript.** Even though we didn't get a "formula" as you might traditionally expect, this generating function $A$ encodes all the information of these distinct square decompositions, to which we can extract the appropriate coefficient. In fact, we do have (formally)
$$
a_n = \frac{A^{(n)}(0)}{n!},
$$
where $A^{(n)}(0)$ is the $n$-th derivative of $A(q)$ evaluated at $q=0$.
In this vein we have to ask, "what is an answer" and "what is formula"...

**Update.** One can easily fashion this SageMath code to compute $a_n$ (though not the most efficient):

```
var('q')
n = 1000 # choose your value n to output a_n = number of decomp of n into distinct squares.
N = 1+ceil(sqrt(n))
A = 1
for k in range(1,N):
    A = A*(1+q^(k^2))
A.coefficients(sparse=False)[n]

---
output:
1269
```

Here $n=1000$, and we get $a_{1000} = 1269$. Also for reference $a_{10000} = 3296089777$ and $a_{128} = 0$. For a more efficient algorithm you can search for *subset sum algorithms* (say https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305843/find-all-subsets-that-sum-to-a-particular-value).

---

**Added.** SageMath to plot the first few $a_n$ values and its asymptotic estimate:

```
var('q')
n = 1000 # choose your value n to output a_n = number of decomp of n into distinct squares.
N = 1+ceil(sqrt(n))
A = 1
for k in range(1,N):
    A = A*(1+q^(k^2))
w = A.coefficients(sparse=False)
z = 2.6123753486854883433485675679240716305708006524000634075733282488149277676882728609962438681263119523829763587721497556981576329
h = list_plot([w[i] for i in range(1,n)],plotjoined=True, color='purple')+list_plot([exp(3 * 2^(-5/3) * pi^(1/3) * ((sqrt(2)-1)*z)^(2/3) * x^(1/3)) * ((sqrt(2)-1)*z)^(1/3) / (2^(4/3) * sqrt(3) * pi^(1/3) * x^(5/6)) for x in range(1,n)],plotjoined=True, color='yellow')
show(h)
```

Comment: How far above $128$ did you search looking for numbers that cannot be represented?  If the range is enough it is often possible to extend it into a proof, but I don't know how much is needed.  If you had checked to $10,000$, say, you might be able to show that any higher number can be brought into the range $129-10,000$ using no squares less than $101^2$.  You could then add the squares that bring you to that range to the solution for whichever number you arrive at.

Comment: You're right, such a proof actually exists that I just found, https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Numbers_not_Sum_of_Distinct_Squares#:~:text=Then%20k%20can%20be%20expressed,distinct%20squares%20by%20Induction%20Hypothesis. I will add edit it in.

Comment: And I see, a reference of yours here! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018801/numbers-which-are-not-the-sum-of-distinct-squares

Comment: I had forgotten I had done it