# What are the numbers that can be uniquely represented as the sum of two squares?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I know that primes of the form $4k+1$ can be represented uniquely as the sum of two squares (not counting order or negative numbers). But there are others like $8$ and $9$ that are not "prime *and* of the form $4k+1$" that can also be represented uniquely.

Is there a general pattern?

Comment: See [OEIS A125022](https://oeis.org/A125022) and a [longer list](https://oeis.org/A125022/b125022.txt)

Comment: All numbers $\geq 128$ (or something close to that) can be written as the sum of two different squares.

Comment: One standard observation that might help: $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ac+bd)^2+(ad-bc)^2$.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I am pretty sure that is not true, and it disagrees with Henry's list.

Comment: To be clear, I am not looking for a list. I am wondering if there is a pattern or rule for numbers on such a list.

Comment: @GarethMa It is true for all integers $\geq 129,$ not $\geq 128.$ See here for details if interested: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018801/numbers-which-are-not-the-sum-of-distinct-squares#:~:text=We%20can%20express%20k%20%2B%201%20%3D%20m,you%20think%20harder%20about%20what%20square%20to%20subtract. Although this is not so closely related to OP's question, which is about numbers which can be written *uniquely* as the sum of two different squares. So yes I realise my comments are not so closely related now.

Answer (score 1):

The page on [mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html) gives the following:

For $n = 2^a\left(\prod_{p_i\equiv 1\mod 4} p_i^{e_i}\right)\left(\prod_{q_j\equiv 3\mod 4} q_j^{f_j}\right)$, define $B = \prod e_i + 1$, and we have

$$r_2'(n) = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{if any }f_j\text{ is odd} \\ \frac{1}{2}B &\text{if }B\text{ is even} \\ \frac{1}{2}(B - (-1)^a) &\text{if }B\text{ is odd} \end{cases}$$

Therefore, assuming all $f_j$ are even, there are three cases:

- If $B$ is even, then $B = 2$, meaning there is exactly one $e_1 = 1$, and

$$n = 2^k p \left(\prod_{q_j\equiv 3\mod 4} q_j^{f_j}\right)^2$$

- Otherwise, either $B = 3$, $a$ is even, i.e.

$$n = 2^{2k} p^2 \left(\prod_{q_j\equiv 3\mod 4} q_j^{f_j}\right)^2$$

- Or, $B = 1$, $a$ is odd, i.e.

$$n = 2^{2k + 1} \left(\prod_{q_j\equiv 3\mod 4} q_j^{f_j}\right)^2$$

**Note:** The formula seems to be wrong for square values.

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT.-The general solution of the diophantine equation $$x^2+y^2=z^2+w^2$$ is given by the identity $$(aX+bY)^2+(aY-bX)^2=(aX-bY)^2+(aY+bX)^2$$ where $a,b$ are arbitrary integers and $X,Y$ are two parameters.

You can verify that both sides give $(a^2+b^2)(X^2+Y^2)$.

What you can try is to find conditions to have $x=z$ or $x=w$ so the corresponding integer numbers have unique representation as sum of squares.